# polymorphic_allocator: how to change the memory resource of a container

Tags: c++, c++17, allocator

Suppose I've a `std::pmr::vector` of `int` already in use. It is already initialized and it contains N items (what's important is that N is greater than 0). Under the hood it uses the memory resource `M1`.
So far so good. It works, I can compare it with another vector of integers that uses a completely different memory resource and so on with all the other fantastic things a polymorphic allocator has to offer.

Now I want to change the underlying memory resource of my vector (put aside all the possible downsides in terms of performance or whatever).

Something like this:

```
template<typename MR>
void setMemoryResource(MR *resource) {
    // ... ??
}
```

How can I manage it so that all the elements are still there after the operation?
I'm asking these for neither the container nor the allocator have a method to set a different memory resource. Therefore I'm even wondering if it's possible.
I can imagine a few ways to do that, but none of them look idiomatic. Actually all of them look like a tricky way around a hole in the API.

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something basic and it's probably as easy as an assignment. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no easy way to. It is intended that you cannot change the memory resource associated with a container during its lifetime. You can make a *new* container with the desired memory resource using the allocator-extended copy/move constructor, but not change the memory resource of existing ones.

Comment: Uhm. Moving an allocator with a different memory resource doesn't assign it to the one in which I'm moving? I mean something along this line: `vec = std::prm::vector<int>{another_resource};`. Yeah, I get the problems in case `vec` isn't empty, but I can't believe there isn't a way to do that.

Comment: No. The allocator does not propagate on assignment. (In fact, the allocator itself has a deleted assignment operator so that you can't assign it by accident.)

Comment: Right. Forgot it. Therefore I cannot even initialize it with a default allocator and assign _the right one_ later (whatever it means for my application). It seems to me another step along the uselessness of allocators as offered by the standard template library unfortunately. :-(